# Mobclix for Android

Tags: android, mobclix

I have MyApp_240x320.apk and MyApp_480x800.apk. I integrated Mobclix to the 240x320 version, works as expected. But the same integration for 480x800 shows nor ads, neither errors in the console. What maybe the problem?

Comment: There may be no inventory. What does logcat say?

Comment: @KennyC nothing in logcat, no errors, exactly the same output as for the 240x320 app